# Asymptotics for solution of transport equation and characteristics

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, hyperbolic-equations

Consider the transport equation $$u_t + v(t,x) \cdot \nabla u = 0.$$
Suppose that the solution of the characteristic equation decays to zero as $t \to \infty$. What happens to the solution of the PDE? Does it also decay to zero?

Comment: So it will depend on your initial condition. For example $u=1$ is solution, and it doesn't decay to $0$. If you are initially bounded and compactly supported, then I think yes, all the trajectories will go to $0$, so $u$ will be $0$ everywhere except in $0$, but the function will remain bounded, so it will be $0$ a.e. in the limit. Remark however that I suppose the convergence might depend on the norm you are considering. If $u$ is unbounded or not compactly supported, it is not clear.

Comment: @LL3.14 Can you clarify what you mean? From the (weak) solution formula, $$\int_{\mathbb R^N} \phi u(t,x)dx = \int_{\mathbb R^N} \phi(X(t,x))u_0(x)dx \qquad \phi \in C^\infty_c,$$ it seems that the support of $u$ doesn't play much of a role.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X(t,y)$ be the flow defined by $X(0,y) = y$ and $\partial_t X(t,y) = v(t,X(t,y))$ and assume to simplify that the inverse flow $Y(t,x)$ is well defined (i.e. $X(t,Y(t,x))=x$). Let $u$ be the solution of
$$
\partial_t u + v\cdot\nabla u = 0.
$$
with initial condition $u(0,x) = f(x)$. Then $u(t,X(t,y))$ is constant by the equation, so $u(t,X(t,y)) = u(0,y) = f(y)$ and the solution is the function
$$
u(t,x) = f(Y(t,x)).
$$

-> Intuitively, since all the trajectories $X$ are converging to $0$, we see that the $Y$ will go in the other direction and go away from $0$, so the value of $u$ at $x$ will be the value of $f$ far away from $0$ (which is $0$ if $f$ is compactly supported).

-> To simplify, assume that $v(t,x) = -x$, so that $X(t,y)= y\,e^{-t} \underset{t\to \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0$. Then $Y(t,x) = x\,e^t$ and
$$
u(t,x) = f(x\,e^t).
$$

- If $f$ is compactly supported, then there is $R>0$ such that $f(y)=0$ when $|y|>R$, and for each point $x≠0$, when $t > \ln(|x|/R)$, then $|x\,e^t|>R$ so that $u(t,x) = 0$. Therefore, $f\to 0$ pointwise on $\mathbb{R}^d\setminus\{0\}$.
- With the same reasoning, if $f = \varphi + c$ with $\varphi$ compactly supported, then $f\to c$ pointwise on $\mathbb{R}^d\setminus\{0\}$
- And we can really get more general profiles by choosing the profile of $f$ at infinity. For example if $f(x) = g(x/|x|)$, then $u(t,x) = g(x/|x|)$ is constant and so converges towards $g(x/|x|)$ with $g$ any function defined on the sphere.

-> Remark in any case that if $f(0)=1$, $f$ is continuous and $f$ is compactly supported, even if $f(x)$ converges to $0$ almost everywhere, it does not converges to $0$ in $L^\infty$ (i.e. uniformly) since $\|u-0\|_{L^\infty} = \|f\|_{L^\infty} = 1$

Comment: Thanks. More in general, do we have the convergence to the Dirac delta?

Comment: In general no, For example, if the initial condition is bounded, then it remains bounded, so it cannot converge to a dirac, and more generally you have no concentration effects. If there is a dirac in the initial condition (let say $f = \delta_{x_0}$ for some fixed $x_0$), then yes, since $\delta_{X_t} \to \delta_0$.

Comment: Thanks! I'm thinking about measure-valued solutions and initial data